# Подписка на событие от Yandex Map

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Хочу подписаться на событие `Update` в Yandex Map. Не могу понять как? В доках не указанно. Если просто написать

```
map.Update = UpdateHandler;
```

Не катит. При этом

```
map.Update()
```

Это уже вызов ф-и `Update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо делать так:

```
YMaps.Events.observe(map, map.Events.Click, UpdateHandler);
```

Подробно можно [посмотреть в примерах](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/examples/).

Answer (score 0):

А так `map.Update(UpdateHandler)`? [Документация](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/ref/reference/map.xml#event-Update) намекает на callback функцию с передаваемым указателем на карту...